# Load data for angularjs unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I want to use some dummy data in an angular unit test. The data is a large javascript array of objects. I'd rather not have this object in my unit test. Is there a way I can load this data into my unit test? In effect, I want the unit test to "include" another file which contains the data. Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a `globals.js` file which I include in my `karma.conf.js` and it looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: "..",

    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ["jasmine"],

...
files: [
      "test/unit/globals.js",
      "app/js/*/**",
]
...
});
};
```

and in my `globals.js` file I just create the dummy data like this:

```
var globals = {
var1: 'mockValue1',
var2: 'mockValue2',
...
}
```

And in my unit tests I just write `var something = globals.var1;` if I want to use it there :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [karma-ng-json2js-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-ng-json2js-preprocessor).

It allows you to do exactly what you want. Have your JSONs in a separate `.json` file and then inject those mock jsons as angular constants into your tests.